# How to use multiple ajax calendars in a single page

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use a calendar to insert dates. Unfortunately, I have to use more than one calendar. For extracting the date from the calendar, I am using Ajax toolkit

```
`<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"  EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" runat="server">
            </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="DateOfPurchase" runat="server"  Height="30px" ReadOnly="true" Width="262px"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPopup" ImageUrl="images/index.jpg" ImageAlign="Bottom"
            runat="server" Height="27px" Width="37px" />

            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateOfPurchase"
            Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
            </cc1:CalendarExtender>`
```

So whenever I add more than one
 `<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"    EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" runat="server">
            </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>`
my program shows error.
And if I use Only one ToolkitScriptManager and multiple  Ajax calendar controls, clicking on only one image button for displaying the calendar, all the calendars,on the page, pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each CalendarExtender must have its own ID

```
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPopup1" ImageUrl="images/index.jpg" ImageAlign="Bottom"
        runat="server" Height="27px" Width="37px" />

        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup1" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateOfPurchase1"
        Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>`
```

```
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPopup2" ImageUrl="images/index.jpg" ImageAlign="Bottom"
        runat="server" Height="27px" Width="37px" />

        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar2" PopupButtonID="imgPopup2" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateOfPurchase2"
        Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>`
```